# How do I copy and move .jpg files from an sd card (D:/) to a folder on the desktop?

Tags: python, file

I am working on a project to copy and rename files from an SD card with the path G:/ to the desktop with the path being C:/Desktop. It wont let me access the other drive so Im wondering what could be the issue.

```
path = "G:/DCIM/100CANON"
images = [f for f in os.listdir(path) if '.CR2' in f.lower()]

for image in images:
    old_path = 'G:/DCIM/100CANON/' + image
    new_path = 'C:/Users/brady/Desktop/emptyFolder/' + image
    shutil.move(old_path, new_path)
```

Answer (score 0):

Line 1: `'.CR2'` cannot be in `f.lower()` since it is upper-case. So the list stays empty. It should be `'.cr2'`.

Comment: I am not getting an error message. It never fills the list so there is nothing for the function to copy

Comment: Oh, I found the error. '.CR2' cannot be in f.lower() since it is upper-case. So the list stays empty. It should be '.cr2'.